# C compare token with string

Tags: c

I read a string from a file composes of two words that I split up with token and want to them compare to my inputs. The first comparison works fine but not the second. The print statement printout the same thing but the check fail. I'm guessing it's due to special end of line character.

```
if(strcmp(argv[2], token[0]) == 0){
    printf("Input1 match\n");
    printf("%s\n", argv[3]);
    printf("%s\n", token[1]);
    if(strcmp(argv[3], token[1]) == 0)
    {
        printf("Input2 match\n");
    }
}
```

Edit: There was a \n character in my second token and using this code to trim the string fix it

```
void strip(char *s) {
    char *p2 = s;
    while(*s != '\0') {
        if(*s != '\t' && *s != '\n') {
            *p2++ = *s++;
        } else {
            ++s;
        }
    }
    *p2 = '\0';
}
```

Comment: You may get better answers if you post the code doing the tokenization.  That is probably where the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your print statements to:

```
printf("[%s]\n", argv[3]);
printf("[%s]\n", token[1]);
```

to see if they're *really* the same. You may well find there's a "hidden" character at the end of the token, such as `<space>` or `\n`.

If it doesn't show up even with that, you can pipe the output through a hex dump program, if you have one available <sup>(a)</sup>, something like:

```
./myprog | od -xcb
```

Then you can examine the output for suspicious characters.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you're on Windows, gVim has a "convert to hex" on the menu, or you can install CygWin or GnuWin32 tools to get things like `od`.

Comment: If it's a nonprinting character this may not help.  Piping the output to `hexdump` or printing the `strlen` would likely be more informative.

Comment: It was a \n character so it shows up in the output. Trimming it fix it. Thanks.